# Data validation doesn't work if Source formula refers to empty cell

Tags: excel, validation

I have a cell with list data validation, which should show different lists depending on other cell content:

```
=IF(D2="",$H$2:$H$4,$I$2:$I$4)
```

It shows correct lists, but it allows to type any value if D2 is empty. The same problem if I use `ISBLANK` function instead of `D2=""`. If I replace `D2=""` by `TRUE`, it correctly shows the list from column H and doesn't allow to type the value not from the list as expected. Is it an Excel bug or I missed something?

Comment: uncheck ignore blank option under settings tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you uncheck the box **Ignore Blanks**.

You can either leave the cell blank or choose from a list and it will not allow an invalid entry.

[image]

[image]